# Views Accordion not working when other Jquery plugins are used

Tags: 7, views, javascript, navigation

I am having problem with Views Accordion when I am using Views Accordion and the Isotope Jquery plugin both on same page.

Isotope Jquery plugin seems to be working fine, but the Views Accordion looks crashed no CSS and functionality is working.

Comment: how are you adding the plugin is it through module?

Comment: Actually Isotope plugin is pasted as a PHP code in to a block and plugin block is displayed inside content region. And Views Accordion is a view block displayed in the right side region.

Comment: Within the Isotope plugin block, I link to two js files lik:

`<script src="[domain]/sites/all/libraries/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`


`<script src="[domain]/sites/all/libraries/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>`

Comment: this is where the issue comes up the jquery is already embedded with in the Drupal. So no need to embed it again. As I mentioned it would be better to go with a module rather than doing it this way.

Comment: I am really sorry, there is no point of using the module

Comment: So have you got this sorted out? If not if it is just a matter of adding the js then you should try doing it through the theme rather than pasting it in the block code as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am currently looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module called http://drupal.org/project/views_isotope

Using that would be better as it would play well with the rest of the js.

The js behavior with in drupal 7 has changed a bit and placing the js directly might not work well in many cases.

Comment: Views Isotope (http://drupal.org/project/views_isotope)

This module cannot be used because I have customized layout and several other functionality which cannot be handled by view isotope module

Comment: I agree with you that this is a problem with D7 behavior when adding `<?php drupal_add_js ?>` or adding a `<script src="[domain]/sites/all/libraries/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` when I remove the js links the views accordion works well.

Comment: I tried using below code to add js files through themes, It did work, but the views accordion dose not still work:

`function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/webbykat.js', array( 
    'scope' => 'header', 
    'weight' => '15' 
  ));
}`

Comment: What is the content of the js you are trying to add?

Comment: these are the two file I am trying to load: 

1> `http://isotope.metafizzy.co/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` 

2> `http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js`

Comment: you dont have to load the jquery-1.7.1.min.js as drupal by default loads jquery.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, then the views accordion works and not the isotope plugin, is it due to version mismatch? D7 is using jQuery UI 1.8.11 and Isotope plugin uses 1.7.1?

Comment: Just for testing why don't you install the views_isotope and see if that way both views accordion and views isotope work together. If it does then you could look into the module and see how they have done it and replicate the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohammed Shameem, I have already tried all the direct approach as you mentioned above, but did not work for me. I did try to install the isotope module, still dose not help